# Drop & Drag into multiple locations

Tags: android

I am creating a Timetable / Schedule application within Android Studio for Autistic children where they can organise their day using 'Activity Images' which can be 'dropped and dragged' into a total of 5 'activity slots' for each day (Monday, Tuesday etc).

I have named each IMAGELOCATION as follows:

MONDAY: 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E 
TUESDAY: 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D, 2E 
WEDNESDAY: 3A, 3B, 3C, 4D, 3E 
THURDAY: 4A, 4B, 4C, 4D, 4E 
FRIDAY: 5A, 5B, 5C, 5D, 5E 
SATURDAY: 6A, 6B, 6C, 6D, 6E 
SUNDAY: 7A, 7B, 7C, 7D, 7E

I have successfully coded it to place an 'Activity Image' into location 1A, however I am not sure how to go about coding it for the rest of the locations.  I have tried copy and pasting the code used previous for the other locations, however when 'dropped and dragged' an image it copied THE SAME IMAGE into all locations that were coded.

```
public class NewScheduleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10;
ImageView activityslotlocation1a, activityslotlocation1b, activityslotlocation1c, activityslotlocation1d, activityslotlocation1e;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newschedulescreen);


    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
    image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);

     activityslotlocation1a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activityslot1a);
    activityslotlocation1b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activityslot1b);
    activityslotlocation1c = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activityslot1c);
    activityslotlocation1d = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activityslot1d);
    activityslotlocation1e = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activityslot1e);

    image1.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    image2.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    image3.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    image4.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    image5.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    image6.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    image7.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    image8.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    image9.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    image10.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);

    activityslotlocation1a.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
    activityslotlocation1b.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
    activityslotlocation1c.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
    activityslotlocation1d.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
    activityslotlocation1e.setOnDragListener(dragListener);

}

View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDragAndDrop(data, myShadowBuilder, v, 0);
        return true;

    }
};

View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        int dragEvent = event.getAction();
        final View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        switch (dragEvent) {

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                break;


            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                // Location 1A

                if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView1) {
                    activityslotlocation1a.setImageResource(R.drawable.art);

                } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView2) {
                    activityslotlocation1a.setImageResource(R.drawable.gohome);

                } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView3) {
                    activityslotlocation1a.setImageResource(R.drawable.bedtime);

                } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView4) {
                    activityslotlocation1a.setImageResource(R.drawable.watchamovie);

                } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView5) {
                    activityslotlocation1a.setImageResource(R.drawable.swimmingclass);

                } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView6) {
                    activityslotlocation1a.setImageResource(R.drawable.cooking);

                } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView7) {
                    activityslotlocation1a.setImageResource(R.drawable.blocks);

                } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView8) {
                    activityslotlocation1a.setImageResource(R.drawable.drink);

                } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView9) {
                    activityslotlocation1a.setImageResource(R.drawable.bedtimestory);

                } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView10) {
                    activityslotlocation1a.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizzanight);
                }

                //view.animate()
                        //.x(activityslotlocation1a.getX())
                        //.y(activityslotlocation1a.getY())
                        //.setDuration(500)
                        //.start();

                MediaPlayer mymedia = MediaPlayer.create(NewScheduleActivity.this,R.raw.whoosh);
                mymedia.start();

                break;
        }


        return true;
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Tip: I would make two arraylists for image and activityslotlocation and then loop through the process initialization and assignment of the listeners. for makeing your code shorter,

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little, give this a try, but listen to the comments and try to trim the code down a little.

```
private Imageview startview;

View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    int dragEvent = event.getAction();
    final View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
    switch (dragEvent) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            startview = v;
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            if(!startview) break;
            if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView1) {
                startview.setImageResource(R.drawable.art);
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView2) {
              startview.setImageResource(R.drawable.gohome);
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView3) {
             startview.setImageResource(R.drawable.bedtime);
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView4) {
              startview.setImageResource(R.drawable.watchamovie);
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView5) {
              startview.setImageResource(R.drawable.swimmingclass);
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView6) {
              startview.setImageResource(R.drawable.cooking);
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView7) {
              startview.setImageResource(R.drawable.blocks);
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView8) {
               startview.setImageResource(R.drawable.drink);
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView9) {
              startview.setImageResource(R.drawable.bedtimestory);
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView10) {
              startview.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizzanight);
            }
           startview = null;
            MediaPlayer mymedia = MediaPlayer.create(NewScheduleActivity.this,R.raw.whoosh);
            mymedia.start();
            break;
    }


    return true;
}
```

};

Comment: Hi Alex. Sorry I also should mention that I'm a bit of Beginner....when I place your code in I get an error with the 'startview = v;' within the ACTION DRAG entered and also an error with the 'if(!startview)' in the ACTION DROP

Comment: Do you maybe have a more direct form contact? email maybe? I could send you screenshots?

Comment: Also the error message is saying:

Incompatible types:
REQUIRED: Android.widget.imageView
FOUND: Android.view.view

Comment: change `case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            startview = v;`to `case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            startview = (ImageView)v;`, that should do the trick.

Comment: Still not working for myself.  Would it be possible for me to send you my project for you to take a look?